# Ruby - Scoping method calls to current class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

On a current Rails app we are building, a user can have company wide preferences, user specific preferences or project specific preferences. When a user creates a Purchase Order, I need to aggregate all these preferences and set the corresponding attributes on the order. I start with Project Preferences and keep going up the hierarchy until I collect all attributes as below.

```
  class Preferences 

    def initialize(project, user)
      @preferences = Preferences.new
      @project = project
      @user = user
    end

    def stage
    end

    def set_preferences
      set_department
    end

  End


  class UserPreferences < Preferences

    def initialize(project, user)
     super(project, user)
     @user_preferences = nil
    end

    def stage
     @user_preferences = @user.preferences
     set_preferences if @user_preferences.present?
     super unless @preferences.valid?
    end 


    def set_department
     @preferences ||= @user_preferences.dept
    end

  end

  class ProjectPreferences < UserPreferences

    def initialize(project, user)
     super(project, user)
     @project_preferences = nil
    end

    def stage
     @project_preferences = @project.preferences
     set_preferences if @project_preferences.present?
     super unless @preferences.valid?
    end 

    def set_department
      @preferences.dept ||= @project_preferences.dept
    end

  end

  def StagePreferences < ProjectPreferences

    def initialize(project, user)
     super(project, user)
    end

   def stage
     super
     @preferences
   end

  end
```

and the method is invoked like below

```
StagePreferences.new(project, current_user).stage
```

I am running into an issue where when I call the set_preferences method from the UserPreferences class (because there were no preferences set for this project), the set_department from UserPreferences is getting called which returns an error as below?

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `dept' for nil:NilClass
from /home/rails/tools/ss/lib/preferences/project_preferences.rb:27:in `set_department'
from /home/rails/tools/ss/lib/preferences/preferences.rb:26:in `set_preferences'
from /home/rails/tools/ss/lib/preferences/user_preferences.rb:17:in `stage'
from /home/rails/tools/ss/lib/preferences/stage_preferences.rb:23:in `stage'
from /home/rails/tools/ss/lib/preferences/project_preferences.rb:17:in `stage'
from /home/rails/tools/ss/lib/preferences/stage_preferences.rb:8:in `stage'
from (irb):8
from /home/rails/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.0.13/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:90:in `start'
from /home/rails/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.0.13/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:9:in `start'
from /home/rails/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.0.13/lib/rails/commands.rb:62:in `<top (required)>'
from bin/rails:4:in `require'
from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

Comment: You assign to `nil`  a `@user_preferences` varialbe and trying to  call `dept` method on `nil`. Check current logic of your classes.

Comment: Thanks, but @user_preferences is set to nil only during initialization. The error is being thrown from the ProjectPreferences class that is calling the set_department on the UserPreferences class. I need it to be scoped only to the method on the ProjectPreferences class.

Comment: Looks like there's more code you're not showing. What's at stage_preferences.rb:23?

Comment: @DaveSchweisguth - This class has multiple methods, and I just whittled it down to a bare minimum.

Comment: It's nice to show as little code as possible, but the backtrace you show hits that line, so it should be in the question so everyone can understand what's going on.

Answer (score 2):

Ruby's Dynamic dispatch uses a 'depth first' search of the methods on the receiver, meaning the your `ProjectPreferences#set_department` method will always get called, and your 'UserPreferences#set_department' method will never get called (FYI, it looks like you've got a typo in this method?).

It is possible to call this method within the current hierarchy using Ruby's `instance_method` method via:

```
UserPreferences.instance_method(:set_department).bind(self).call
```

Which allows you to call this 'unreachable' method on self as if ProjectPreferences had not overridden it.

However, I'd question the requirement to have so many Preference subclasses, as this question highlights, debugging problems in the class hierarchy become increasingly more complex.

Comment: I wanted to avoid calling individual class methods, and I can rather rename the individual instance methods and call them directly from within the UserPreferences class. The only advantage that the instance_method lets me do is use the same method names, which no longer serve a purpose. Did I get that right?

Comment: The thing is that when it calls #set_department in Preferences#set_preferences but using StagePreferences or ProjectPreferences instance to call it on interpreter looks for  #set_department from 'bottom' of hierarchy(StagePreferences class) and goes up until first occurrence is found(ProjectPreferences#set_department). Thus never come up to UserPreferences#set_department unless you directly use UserPreferences instance and not its child. Hope that is clear